# close window event in java

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, window

I added an window state listener as follow:

```
this.addWindowStateListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            ExitAction.getInstance().actionPerformed(null);
        }

    });
```

But when I'm using the X close button the event is not called.
I think it's something to do with netbean jdesktop framework. But I can't find what could be the problem. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`windowClosing` is part of the `WindowListener` interface. Use `addWindowListener` instead of `addWindowStateListener`.

Comment: +1.  note that a `WindowStateListener` is used to handle events that are triggered when the window is minimized or maximized, etc, but not closed.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you use a WindowListener for this.

Check out [Closing an Application](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) for an approach I use, although I must admit I've never tried it with Netbeans since I don't use an IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Not answering your question directly (since an answer has already been given), but I assume you want to quit your program (or just hide a window) on exit. There is a shorter solution for these situations:

```
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just debugged a similar problem in my Swing program. It turned out to be a Java bug that kills the system UI events when ImageIO is called before the Swing UI is created. See here for a minimal example -

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964138/osx-specific-new-java-ui-bug-reproducable-java-imageio-close-window-event-bug

This bug stops the system UI events, such as window-close, from being delivered to Java.

Answer (score 0):

As the Java documentation says, to actually close the window the listener should invoke the window's dispose or setVisible(false) method.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for helping me solve the problem. I don't fully understend it but the following code solve the problem:

```
    Frame[] frames = Frame.getFrames();
    for(Frame f: frames){
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                ExitAction.getInstance().actionPerformed(null);
            }

        });
    }
```

It look as if the framework add additional frames.
Thanks,

Answer (score -2):

As others have pointed out the WindowListener is what you are after... but you should do this from now on when overriding a method:

```
this.addWindowStateListener(
    new WindowAdapter() 
    {
        @Overrides
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
        {
            ExitAction.getInstance().actionPerformed(null);
        }

    });
```

Then the compiler will tell you when you are not actually overriding a method and are instead adding a new method (that in this case will never be called).

Comment: WindowAdapter is both a WindowListener and a WindowStateListener. The problem here is that it's being added as a WindowStateListener so the methods it has as a WindowListener are not called.

Comment: ah true, I didn't know it implemented more than WindowListener.  How odd... apparently they added that in 1.4.  Before 1.4, if Java had annotations, what I said would have worked :-) (not deleting the answer since it is valid as a general rule just not in this specific case)