# How to perform a task before a window/frame is closed?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

The `JFrame` provides a method `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` . I want to run some code before this Frame is actually closed. How do I do that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984195/close-window-event-in-java

Comment: If you want to veto the closing, you will also want to change `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` to something more like `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, but then don't forget to run the actual exit code

Comment: @WChargin Why would you ever want to do that for? ... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
        // The window is closing
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Implement WindowListener and capture window closing event. Something like-

```
    yourWindow.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
             // do something here
         }
    });
```

Comment: Got it. JFrame is a sub class of Window and - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html

Answer (score 2):

Do this

```
frame.addWindowsListener(new WindowAdapter() {

    public void windowClosing() {
        // do your work here
        frame.dispose();
    }         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer [WindowListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) documentation

Comment: Is there some method in the JFrame API which lets you run a method before closing it ?

Comment: @SuperStar put your own (user-defined) method in : `public void windowClosing() {yourMethod();}`