# When you close a GUI with the little X

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, thread-safety, threadpool

If you close a GUI using the the little X in the top right of the form, does that kill all your threads as well?

If not, how to you catch that event so I can put in some close down code?

Comment: It will *kill* the threads if and only if you execute `setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` on the main JFrame.

Comment: What happened when you tested it?

Comment: Even though Luiggi solved the main issue, you could always add a `WindowListener`, which activates when a `Window` gets closed.

Comment: make other threads [daemon](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616109/Java-Thread-Tutorial#dtr)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

To execute some code on closing have a look at this. [close window event in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984195/close-window-event-in-java)

Comment: Do I  put that in the constructor:

public class MainWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public MainWindow() {
        this.pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        initComponents();
    }

Comment: exactly, but only for "good style": why you doesn't import javax.swing.JFrame ? It would make your code more easy to read.

Answer (score 2):

> If you close a GUI using the the little X in the top right of the form, does that kill all your threads as well?

Yes, if the default close operation is `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` as mentioned by Luiggi.  OTOH it is best not to simply 'kill' threads arbitrarily.

> If not, how to you catch that event so I can put in some close down code?

Set a default close operation of `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` and add a `WindowListener` or `WindowAdapter`.  In the listener, dispose of the GUI and end the threads.

See [How to Write Window Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) for details.

Comment: `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` might be an alternative as well, I suppose, unless it is required to perform the `dispose` in a specific order, relative to the other closing operations.